# nhibernate generated sql - alias for table

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria, sql-execution-plan

Is there's a way of stopping NHibernate to generate alias for tables when generating queries?

I have an execution plan at SQL server and I need to apply this plan on my queries,but i can't since nhibernate every time I execute a select query I get a different alias for my table.

for example:

```
from dbo.Accounts accountdet0_ where  accountdet0_.AccountID = 1366
```

Is there's a way an attribute or configuration that I can do to control this aliasing?

Thanks in advanced for any help

Answer (score 0):

*While one should **not** count on the generated aliases for some custom stuff* - from perspective of the SQL Server ... these generated aliases are pretty stable.

Run the same query *(even with **different** prameters)* as many times you want - the resulted SQL will **be the same**.

And even more, because of parametrized syntax like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT department0_.Department_ID as Department1_200_0_,
 department0_.Code as Code200_0_, 
 department0_.Description as Description200_0_, ...
FROM [dbo].[Department] department0_ 
WHERE department0_.Department_ID=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

The execution plan will be reused for any amount of similar queries with just different parameters...